# Is there a publicly available higher resolution equivalent to Landsat 8/9 TIRS?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, land-surface-temperature

I have a strong feeling the answer to this question is no.  That said, I'd love to be wrong.

I'm looking to estimate land surface temperature at a higher resolution than the 100m bands (10 and 11) on the Landsat 8 and 9 Thermal Infrared Sensor (TIRS).  I have access to much higher resolution red and NIR bands (5m), so having the temperature data would also allow me to gain accuracy for the Land Surface Temperature measurements.

I see that there is ASTER data which covers similar bands as TIRS, but it's at 90m.  That's hardly better.  The 15m or 30m bands would be nice, but I recognize those are likely not suitable bands for measuring temps using the Jiminez-Munoz algorithm.

Alternatively, is there a different algorithm for computing LST without having to rely on the 10.5 to 12.5 um bands?

Comment: I am not aware of any high res, free, publicly available thermal products. However, there are commercial options. Check out SatVu: https://www.satellitevu.com/imaging-specification

Comment: Wow.  That is seriously impressive.